# Facebook share error: Object at URL of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

✋

When I paste the URL of my blog in Facebook debugger, its not picking the title and also the image. In view source of my page, the og:title and also og:image are getting rendered but facebook **scraper** is not reading any.

Object at URL 'http://blog.la-pigiste.com/2017/09/20/diy-faire-son-terrazzo-granito-do-it-yourself-inspiration-tendance-tutoriel/' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

Facebook debugger also says "{
"error": {
"message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 104,
"fbtrace_id": "BMdGG7oTu6k"
}
}"

but i don't no what does it means ....

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ says, _“Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received”_ - so there seems to be some kind of network/connectivity issue.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to fetch new scrape information for your URL through the [Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) you get the error:

```
Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

In other words, your web server didn't reply in 10 seconds and the crawler timed out.

It looks like you configured your web server to behave differently when the request is coming from the Facebook Crawler.

You can verify this using curl.

Fetching your URL with curl's default User Agent works fine:

```
$ curl -v 'http://blog.la-pigiste.com/2017/09/20/diy-faire-son-terrazzo-granito-do-it-yourself-inspiration-tendance-tutoriel/' > /dev/null

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 149.56.140.68...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to blog.la-pigiste.com (149.56.140.68) port 80 (#0)
> GET /2017/09/20/diy-faire-son-terrazzo-granito-do-it-yourself-inspiration-tendance-tutoriel/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: blog.la-pigiste.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Wed, 20 Sep 2017 10:34:37 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 117446
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Last-Modified: Wed, 20 Sep 2017 07:25:20 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Powered-By: PleskLin
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT
<
{ [956 bytes data]
100  114k  100  114k    0     0   159k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  159k
* Connection #0 to host blog.la-pigiste.com left intact
```

Anyway, when the Facebook crawler User Agent is used (`facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`), the web server replies differently and only after about 14 seconds:

```
$ curl -v -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" 'http://blog.la-pigiste.com/2017/09/20/diy-faire-son-terrazzo-granito-do-it-yourself-inspiration-tendance-tutoriel/' > /dev/null

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 149.56.140.68...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to blog.la-pigiste.com (149.56.140.68) port 80 (#0)
> GET /2017/09/20/diy-faire-son-terrazzo-granito-do-it-yourself-inspiration-tendance-tutoriel/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: blog.la-pigiste.com
> User-Agent: facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
> Accept: */*
>
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:14 --:--:--     0< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Wed, 20 Sep 2017 10:37:15 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
< X-Pingback: http://blog.la-pigiste.com/xmlrpc.php
< Link: <http://blog.la-pigiste.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/", <...>; rel=shortlink
< Set-Cookie: wfvt_983661238=59c244cfe4c12; expires=Wed, 20-Sep-2017 11:07:03 GMT; Max-Age=1800; path=/; httponly
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Powered-By: PleskLin
<
{ [838 bytes data]
100  124k    0  124k    0     0   8507      0 --:--:--  0:00:15 --:--:-- 36126
* Connection #0 to host blog.la-pigiste.com left intact
```

Ensure that your web server replies in time and with the correct HTML and the crawler will be able to fetch your OG tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You just remind me of using curl to debug.